# Problem with views exposed filters and cyrillic й symbol

Tags: 7, views

I use views exposed filter as search string with "contain" operator.
The filter works normally, but somewhy does not work with cyrillic symbol 'й' if it is placed at end of a word (so it have space after й).

So for example I have words *красный*, *бархатный*, *койот*, *йодоформ*, *ковбойская*

The first two words cannot be found and the view shows no result. But other words can be found.
The position of й in search string does not matter. For example I can find *ковбойская* when I enter *ковбой* in search field. But if I enter *красный* I can't find this word, but *красны* shows me *красный* word.

Here is the SQL request formed by views

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('product')) AND (node.title LIKE '%красный%' ESCAPE '\\') ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

So why it happens and how to avoid this bug?

Comment: I have zero knowledge on cyrillic, but looking at your question it did not make sense. Your question describes the й, but then the example words you give end with a u. When I hit edit and saw it in the editor, the word changed. Is there some combination of letters leading to a different display? Since it appears here as well, this might not be a Drupal specific problem?.